# Barnard's Exact Test (Boschloo's variant) when distribution is hypergeometric

Tags: self-study, statistical-power, contingency-tables, hypergeometric-distribution

Let's say, we have a standard $2 \times 2$ contingency table and because of low sample size we're about to use some type of Exact Test, e.g. Fisher's Exact Test (FET) or Barnard's Exact Test.

It's well known that a Boschloo's test, which is a particular variant of Barnard's Exact Test, is Uniformly More Powerful than Fisher's Exact Test.

How would behave a Boschloo's test when applied to a $2 \times 2$ table which comes from a hypergeometric actual sampling distribution (**that is both marginals fixed**)?

Which of these scenarios takes place in such situation?

1. Boschloo's or any other variant of Barnard's Exact Test cannot be applied when the actual sampling distribution is hypergeometric, because that could in some situations lead to erroneous or awry results. Do not try this at home ;-)
2. Boschloo's test is the only one variant of Barnard's test that is somewhat resistant to hypergeometric distribution, but it'll lead to **reduced power even below power of FET** applied to the same situation.
3. Boschloo's test is the only one variant of Barnard's test that is somewhat resistant to hypergeometric distribution, but it'll lead to **reduced power, but still at least as powerful as FET**.
4. Another embodiment of Barnard's Exact Test (other than Boschloo's) can fullfil the statement from **2nd** point.
5. Another embodiment of Barnard's Exact Test (other than Boschloo's) can fullfil the statement from **3rd** point.
6. Any variant of Barnard's Exact Test is relevant to hypergeometric distribution, giving reliable and reasonable results, but it's power advantage over FET vanishes.

Can you indicate which of these cases really happen is a such situation?
Could you show an example or a counterexample to back up your opinion?

---

I absolutely understand that Boschloo's/Barnard's test works fine supposing at least one of the marginals isn't fixed (at least binomial distribution), but I cannot make it up with the fact that Boschloo's is said to be the Uniformly Most Powerful (a test with the greatest power $1-\beta$ among all test of given significance level $\alpha$). Is the catch in that **all possible tests** means **all possible tests concerning exactly the same space of $2 \times 2$ tables?**

Comment: Boschloo's test doesn't have the right *size* when the marginal totals are fixed - the sampling space includes tables that are impossible by design & therefore irrelevant.

Comment: @Scortchi I like your brief answer. I know that if there's a glimmer of hope that at least one marginal isn't fixed (at least binomial distrib.) Boschloo's test would work, but I cannot make it up with a statement that Boschloo's test is said to be UMP, a test with the greatest possible power $1-\beta$ among **all possible tests** od a given level $\alpha$. Is the catch in that **all possible tests** means **all possible tests concerning exactly the same space of $2 \times 2$ tables**? Is this the source of my misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes. (BTW it's the one-tailed tests that are UMP; Bernard's/Boschloo's unconditionally, Fisher's conditionally). The argument for using Fisher's test even when sampling from two independent binomial distribution is that the marginal totals are nearly ancillary - so tables with different margins are *almost* irrelevant even if possible.

Comment: @Scortchi So, to sum it all up: You recommend me to use FET over any Barnard's test? I've focused my attention on Barnard's test to get the most powerful results even with low number of samples? So, if you were me and had tables with low counts (total sum of a few dozens), would you be more eager to choose FET over BET? I simply thought that BET can only improve my results.

Comment: If the marginal totals are fixed by design, Barnard's test (as well as variants that use test statistics that order the sample space a little differently) is certainly inappropriate. Consider the table with marginal totals each equal to three: the true probability of either of the more extreme tables is 1/10, the p-value from the two-tailed FET; but if a two-independent-binomials sampling scheme was erroneously assumed, the calculated p-value would be 1/32.

Comment: If only one margin's fixed by design, it's debatable. Conditioning on (approximate) ancillaries is a sound principle, but the cost in this case can be high, reducing the sample space to just a smattering of tables.

Comment: @Scortchi Thanks a lot for a comprehensive answer. The last case of fixed by design only one magrinal is my case. Probably I would try both of them with conducting small power simulation to ultiamately choose the best one. Thank you once again.